# How to convert a PL SQL collection into json_object?

Tags: json, oracle, object, plsql, collections

I have a type named codelist if table of varchar. a variable called "final" of type codelist needs to be converted as json_object.

Like this `New = ('1','2','3')` needs to be converted to json format like below

```json
{
  "New" : ['1','2','3']
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
declare

   tag1  json_object_t;

   tag2  json_object_t;

   array json_array_t;

begin

   tag1:= json_object_t();

   tag1.put('Date',  sysdate);
   tag1.put('Your header', "hellow");

   tag2:= json_object_t();

   tag2.put('pos1', test(1).1);
   tag2.put('pos2', teste(2).2);

   array.append(tag2);

 end;
```

If I wasn't very clear, you can follow this link - https://dzone.com/articles/relational-to-json-with-plsql

Comment: Hi Mateus, Thank you for your response. But I want to convert a collection into a json object. Could you please help for that one

Answer (score 0):

The `json` constructor in Oracle Database 23c can automatically [convert PL/SQL record and array variables to JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/adjsn/json-in-oracle-database.html#GUID-F04556DD-B435-425E-8EA6-FBE636FEEA2C):

```
declare
  type rec is record (
    a1 date, a2 varchar2(10)
  );
  type arr is table of rec;
  r rec;
  a arr;
begin
  r := rec ( sysdate, '23c' );
  a := arr ( r );
  dbms_output.put_line ( json_serialize ( json ( r ) returning varchar2 pretty ) );
  dbms_output.put_line ( '*************' );
  dbms_output.put_line ( json_serialize ( json ( a ) returning varchar2 pretty ) );
end;
/
{
  "A1" : "2023-05-26T10:02:13",
  "A2" : "23c"
}
*************
{
  "1" :
  {
    "A1" : "2023-05-26T10:02:13",
    "A2" : "23c"
  }
}
```